# Netbeans to Eclipse migration for Java Projects

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, migration, libraries

I currently switched to eclipse and trying to migrate my projects. I created a java-workspace and used 'File->Open Projects from File System'.

The project with all the folders is added, not only the 'src' but everything I put into it (datasheets, documentation,...). Also the libraries are added two times. One time in the folder and what seems like a link to the compiled library.

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcWI7.png)

In netbeans I just added the desired library to the /libs folder and linked it to the project.

Can I manually add folders and/ or libraries to existing projects? Why are there two instances of the libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using *Open Projects from File System*, **folders containing `.java` files** has been configured as **source folders** (source code intended to be compiled). This can be undone via **right-click *Build Path > Remove from Build Path*** (the reverse function is *Build Path > Use as Source Folder*).

In the *Package Explorer*, source folders are shown as virtual folders. **If the source folder is not a subfolder of the project**, it is **displayed** as virtual folder **in addition** to the project subfolder to be able to navigate to that non-source project subfolder (in your case you have a single `src` source folder and in addition to the non-source folder `lib` you have multiple virtual `lib/...` source folders).

The node ***Referenced Libraries*** lists all JARs and class folders on the *Java Build Path* (classpath/modulepath). To remove something from the *Build Path*, right-click it and choose *Build Path > Remove from Build Path*. JARs can be added to the *Build Path* by right-clicking the JAR and choosing *Build Path > Add to Build Path*. Class folders can be added only via ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path*** in the tab ***Libraries*** with the button *Add Class Folder...*.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is a workaround or good practice for migration:

- Create a new Java-Project in Eclipse
- add desired Folder structure (including /libs)
- In 'Project->Properties -- Libraries' add libraries manually
- Clean and Build Project

I have to test functionality and stability but it seems ok.